# PHP regular expressions to filter results

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of several email addresses which look like the following

```
smtp:email1@myemail.com
smtp:email2@something.myemail.com
SMTP:email3@myemail.com
X400: //some random line
```

Is there any way I can only get the emails which only end in myemail.com?  So from the above, this would be

```
email1@myemail.com
email3@myemail.com
```

So it should get rid of any random lines, and it should also ignore it if there is anything else in the string e.g. something.

I have managed to get some data by doing

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(@)
```

Probably not the best way but it gets me whats infront of the @ sign.  Any help filtering these out appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you are specifically looking for `myemail.com` domain names, and excluding sub domains yo could use `([a-zA-Z]+)(@)myemail.com`. Would that not suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a regex to filter only emails from domain `myemail.com`:

```
<?php

$emailList = <<< LOL
smtp:email1@myemail.com
smtp:email2@something.myemail.com
SMTP:email3@myemail.com
X400: //some random line
LOL;

preg_match_all('/smtp:(.*?@myemail\.com)$/im', $emailList , $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches[1]);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => email1@myemail.com
    [1] => email3@myemail.com
)
*/
```

---

**Demo:**

http://ideone.com/hcd0aa

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
smtp:(.*?@myemail\.com)$

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Greedy quantifiers

Match the character string “smtp:” literally «smtp:»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?@myemail\.com)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character string “@myemail” literally «@myemail»
   Match the character “.” literally «\.»
   Match the character string “com” literally «com»
Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any «$»
```